# Execute a query using powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

I want to run a query using powershel. I want to do automated deployment and powershell proves to be a challenge for me. As I am quite new to it. I found a query that can do the deployment of the SSIS package, but I need to use a powershell command as I will be doing it from VSTS.

The query is:

```
DECLARE @ProjectBinary AS varbinary(max)
DECLARE @operation_id AS bigint
SET @ProjectBinary = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '<project_file_path>.ispac', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BinaryData)

EXEC catalog.deploy_project @folder_name = '<target_folder>',
    @project_name = '<project_name',
    @Project_Stream = @ProjectBinary,
    @operation_id = @operation_id out
```

I tried inserting the code into the following sample

```
$dataSource = “.\SQLEXPRESS”
$user = “user”
$pwd = “1234”
$database = “Test”
$connectionString = “Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=False;”
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$query = “SELECT * FROM Person”
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
$result = $command.ExecuteReader()
```

But it did not work, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I also tried closing the connection

```
$connection.Close() and nothing.
```

Comment: Why not try [Invoke-SqlCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps)?

Comment: I am trying to use Invoke-Sqlcmd, but the problem is that it needs an domain user and when I run the command from vsts it doesnt work. I am trying to impersonate a domain user, but Invoke-Sqlcmd does not accept the -Credential $Creds at the end of the command I am running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the connection object

```
$sb = New-Object System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder
$sb.set_ConnectionString($dbconnectionstring)
$serverName = $sb.server
$databaseName = $sb.database
$userName = $sb.'user id'
$password = $sb.password
```

I have this function that is helpfull in Validating the SQL Connection

```
function Test-SQLConnection {    
    [OutputType([bool])]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            Position = 0)]
        $ConnectionString
    )
    try {
        $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $ConnectionString;
        $sqlConnection.Open();
        $sqlConnection.Close();
        return $true;
    }
    catch {
        return $false;
    }
}
```

Then test the connection and use `Invoke-Sqlcmd` , as you said its not accepting $cred can you try passing the $userName $pwd directly like this ?

```
if(Test-SQLConnection $dbconnectionstring)
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $databaseName -Query $query -Username $username -Password $password
```

Comment: thanks to all, at the end, I used Invoke-Sqlcmd like you both suggested it.